# Can I run Solr server without running rake command for rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, full-text-search, rake-task

Is there any alternate way for running solr server without running rake command for rails application like providing all those solr related classes into single jar and then use that jar.

Please suggest some of the solutions regarding this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you checked Sunspot (the best haha), but you can use the start/stop commands, for example: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#sunspot_rails

```
bundle exec sunspot-solr start -p 8983
```

Also check this out for an example https://gist.github.com/doitian/1795439 (integrates Sunspot with Capistrano, but you can get an idea of the implementation)